# Return string of first character if it contains more than 4 characters, otherwise return the last character

Tags: java

The question is: Given a string return the first character in the string if it contains
more than 4 characters, and the last character otherwise.
Example out comes below

```
firstOrLastChar("kwk") -> 'k'
firstOrLastChar("gals") -> 's'
firstOrLastChar("uocrws") -> 'u'
```

This is the code I've gotten done, but it returns a char not a string so i get this type of error of it being incompatible types. really lost on how to go about it

```
  if (str.length() > 4)
        return str.charAt(0);
    return str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it looks like you want to return a `String` type  instead of `char` type, then you can do following :

```
if (str.length() > 4)
        return String.valueOf(str.charAt(0));
    return String.valueOf(str.charAt(str.length() - 1));
```

Comment: Or avoiding the duplication, `return String.valueOf(str.charAt(str.length() > 4? 0: str.length() - 1));` (or if the ternary operator is too advanced: `int position; if(str.length() > 4) position = 0; else position = str.length() - 1; return String.valueOf(str.charAt( position));`